# How do I handle the MessageReceived event from DatagramSocket inside a MF MediaSource class?

Tags: com, windows-runtime, udp, c++-cx, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to read mulitcast data from a UDP socket from within a Media Foundation MediaSource class.  The `DatagramSocket` class in WinRT throws an event (`MessageReceived`) that contains the `IInputStream` for reading the data received.

However, I have not been able to attach an event handler from the MediaSource class.  I *believe* it is because the MF MediaSource class is not a WinRT class (but instead a COM class).  In any case, I'm not sure how I could get the data from the `MessageReceived` event handler from an external class into my MF MediaSource.  I will be streaming video packets over UDP...

Any suggestions on strategies to take would be very welcome.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using IMFMediaSource interface? This is not supported for metro apps. Or are you trying to use Windows::Media::Core::MediaStreamSource? This is supported as a media source for Windows XAML MediaElement and is probably the class you want to try and use.

Comment: (Note, WMC::MediaStreamSource is Windows 8.1+ only.)

Comment: I am using IMFMediaSource and it does work with metro apps.  I've got another Win8.1 metro app (and WP8.1) that employs a custom Media Source (using IMFMediaSource) to play MKV files.  In any case, I just got a hint that I should be using WRL to "activate it as a WinRT component".  I am currently exploring what that means...

Comment: Are you wrapping it in a `ComPtr` instance? That might do the trick.